# Which distribution program: Developer / Enterprise?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

I am creating an App for a music ensemble. This ensemble wants to give away the visitors who attend the concert this app. On the other day this app could be in the appStore as an App with a certain price.
Should this be done with changing its price on a daily basis? Or is there a more practicle way for it?

Which **kind** of account I should advice the ensemble to take?
Or should I bring it to the app store as an Ad Hoc App? Or Custom B2B App Distribution?
Or should they do it via in-House distribution?

a developer or Enterprise programm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not the enterprise program. The enterprise license allows you to build and deploy iOS apps on devices owned by the enterprise or by the employees of the enterprise. Distributing apps to general customers would be a license violation.

There are two ways to solve your problem using a standard license:

1) Publish a paid app on the app store. If the number of customers who attend the concert is less, give away app store promo codes to them, sell the app to the rest of the customers.

2) Publish a free app on the app store. Have some kind of login mechanism. Give away user ids and passwords to customers who attend the concert. Have an in-app purchase for all others, to get full functionality.

Comment: So with option 2 They dont have to buy a Programm. I do it via my account and let the payments go to their accounts? (I am sorry for this trivial question but as you see I am a new bee)

Comment: O Vin Thank you so much for these answers! I couldn't get the info from developer.apple.com and on the phone to our Apple Store in Amsterdam they couldn't help me as well! So thumbs up! thanx!